# Media Query Only Affects Elements/Classes in Index.html, Not Other Routes

Tags: html, css, routes, media-queries, meta-tags

So I'm trying to make my website mobile-responsive as I have it how I want it to look on a desktop. However, my media queries won't work for classes in any other view than the index.html and I can't figure out why.

Index.html:

html ng-app='skypeClone'

`

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/> Have tried media queries with and without this-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <title>Skype Clone</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller='mainCtrl'>

<ui-view class="view"></ui-view>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.temasys.com.sg/skylink/skylinkjs/0.6.x/skylink.complete.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/mainCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/helpCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/loginCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/loginSvc.js"></script>
<script src="js/createUserCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/createUserSvc.js"></script>
<script src="js/service.js"></script>
<script src="js/userHomeCtrl.js"></script>
</body
</html>
```

`
If the commented out code isn't showing up, I have tried media queries with and without the meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"

Other Route:

`

```
<div id="background-setter-homepage">
  <div id="header-wrap">
    <div id="header">
        <button class="button" id="help" ui-sref='help'>Help</button>
        <button class="button" id="about" ui-sref='about'>About</button>
        <button class="button" id="login" ui-sref='login'>Login</button>
    </div>
  </div>
     <br><br>
    <div class="middleOfPage" id="container">
      <div id="text-and-button">
      <h2 id="phrase">Skyclone keeps the world talking, for free</h2> <br>
      <button class="button" id="getStarted" ui-sref='createUser'>Create An Account</button>
      <div>
    </div>

</div>
```

`

All I want to test just to get it to work is to have the class 'phrase' of the h2 element turn red when the screen gets to a certain max-width.

CSS:

`

```
@media (max-width: 375px) {
  #phrase{
    color: lightgreen;
  }
}
```

`
I've Also tried

`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #phrase{
       color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```

`
The above code doesn't work, however it will work if I select the class on ui-view in the index.html and set the visibility to none at the same width. So It's kind of working...but not really.

Have any of you run into this problem before? I'm currently at a loss. Any and all help is SUPER APPRECIATED!! Thanks in advance (:

Answer (score 1):

If setting visibility to none in the same media query does work, maybe all you need is to change `color: lightgreen;` to `color: lightgreen !important;`

Have you tried that yet?

Comment: I hadn't tried that yet, it worked! Thank you so much!